# Alternative method in PDO for mysql_result() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been using a mysql abstraction class in php and now I want to make the class more      usable and solid by using PDO . In my class I had used mysql_result() function which takes three parameters :

- result: The result resource that is being evaluated. This result comes from a call mysql_query().
- row: The row number from the result that's being retrieved. Row numbers start at 0.
- field: The name or offset of the field being retrieved.

How could I achieve similar output by using PDO ?

Here is the code written with native mysql functions.

```
public function SQLtoJSON($query, $indented = false)
    {
        $query = mysql_query($query) or die ('MyJSON - SQLtoJSON - Cannot make query');

        if (!$numFields = mysql_num_fields($query)) {
            $this->errors[] = 'SQLtoJSON - Cannot get number of MySQL fields';
            return false;
        }

        $fields = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
            $fields[$i] = mysql_field_name($query, $i);

        if (!$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query)) {
            $this->errors[] = 'SQLtoJSON - Cannot get number of MySQL rows';
            return false;
        }

        $res = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
            $res[$i] = array();
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($fields); $j++)
                $res[$i][$fields[$j]] = mysql_result($query, $i, $j);
        }

        $json = json_encode($res);
        if ($indented == false)
            return $json;
```

and here is the updated version of the code using PDO:

```
class MySql_To_Json
{

    private $connection;
    public $errors = array();

    public function __construct($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name)
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name",   $db_username, $db_password);
    }

    public function MySQLtoJSON($query)
    {
        $query = $this->connection->query($query) or die("Unable to execute the query");
        if (!$numFields = $query->columnCount()) {
            $this->errors[] = "Unable to get the number of fields";
            return false;
        }

        $fields = array();
        $colNames = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {
            $fields[$i] = $query->getColumnMeta($i);
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $colNames[] = $field['name'];
            }
        }

        if (!$numRows = $query->rowCount()) {
            $this->errors[] = "Unable to get the number of rows";
            return false;
        }

    // return $numRows;
        $result = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {
            $result[$i] = array();
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($field); $j++) {
                return $result[$i][$field[$j]] = $query->fetch($i);
            }
        }

        $json = json_encode($result);
        return $json;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review the [PDO manual](http://php.net/book.pdo), where you may find the [`PDOStatement` class](http://php.net/pdostatement), which contains the methods you're looking for, like `fetch`.  Please keep in mind that use of `mysql_result` is rather rare, as the behavior is a bit ... weird.

Comment: You may do `fetchAll()` then access the row by array key, but honestly I'd advise you refactor your code not to depend on `mysql_result()` behavior.  If you are cherry-picking rows, it often means your query could be performed more intelligently to return only what's needed to begin with, and if you are looping with `mysql_result()`, that may be better refactored into a more conventional fetch loop.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, Thank you for your reply. Actually I've a class that converts a mysql query to a json object. The class was written using the mysql database specific functions. Now I want to convert the class using PDO to extend the features more. mysql_query(), mysql_result() will be deprecated soon. I've stuck into mysql_result(). If you are interested, I can share my code to you :)

Comment: @MahmudurRahmanShibly Post the relevant code. Dedicated uses of `mysql_result()` are kind of exotic, so there's a good chance you really only need a simple fetch loop coupled with something like `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, can't paste the code here. Still don't have enough privilege. Btw, I've figured out a way. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski, Ok. I'm going to edit my post and share my code there :)

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I've edited my post :) Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected and alluded to in the comments, your original use of `mysql_result()` was unnecessary. What you had in the old class was a collection of C-style incremental `for` loops, which are rarely appropriate in PHP. Instead it's much more common to iterate arrays with `foreach` and when dealing with database APIs, to do something like:

```
// This is the normal and easy way to get an associative array of results:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
```

...where you don't need to worry about the number of rows or columns.

In any case, all of that is entirely unnecessary now and can be replaced with a single call to [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) in PDO, since all it did was retrieve all rows into a column-name indexed array. That is about as standard as a fetch operation gets.

```
   // ALL of this...
   // $res = array();
   // for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
   //     $res[$i] = array();
   //     for ($j = 0; $j < count($fields); $j++)
   //         $res[$i][$fields[$j]] = mysql_result($query, $i, $j);
   // }

   // ...may be replaced with simply:
   $res = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This also means that you don't *really need* the two preceding blocks which retrieve the number of rows and columns.  All of that is implicit in the call to `fetchAll()`.  The only parts you actually now need are the query and the fetch:

```
public function MySQLtoJSON($input_query)
{
    // Do your query...
    $query = $this->connection->query($input_query) or die("Unable to execute the query");

    // Fetch the rows as associative arrays
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // And encode it as JSON
    $json = json_encode($result);
    return $json;
}
```

Note that since you are executing arbitrary SQL statements in the `$query` parameter, you will need to be cautious about what gets passed in there to avoid SQL injection. If you are accepting any user input rather than static queries, you'll need to look into adapting this to use [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and execute them as parameterized queries.

Comment: Excellent ! learned a lot ! thank you for your wonderful explanation.